# Connecting to IPtv host along with PPPoE connection

Tags: networking, local, pppoe, iptv

I use TL-MR3420 router to connect internet. I also have IPtv subscription from my city. So when I connect to Internet(PPPoE) I cannot connect to IPtv address ( 10.168.*.*). Is there a way to use both at the same time? Thanks